# Make this temporary dimension Permanent "Revit"

Tags: revit-api, revit, revit-2015

I am trying to dimension the parts. While dimensioning, I am getting a message stating, "Make this temporary dimension Permanent". How shall I get the permanent dimension without clicking anything in UI.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What parts?  Do you have screen shots of what you're experiencing?

Comment: Part is nothing but an Revit element. I am trying to attach the Dimensions to that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would analyse the exact differences caused in the Revit database on the elements involved and their parameters by executing the manual modification. Once you have discovered exactly what is changed by the manual UI interaction, you can probably replicate the same changes programmatically through the API. Here is a more exhaustive description of how to address a Revit API programming task:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/01/virtues-of-reproduction-research-mep-settings-ontology.html#3